# Почему "лягте" пишется без мягкого знака?

Tags: орфография, морфология

Есть такое правило:

> Мягкий знак в глаголах пишется в форме
> повелительного наклонения после
> согласных: *отрежь*, *одень*.

Тогда почему пишется *ляг* или *лягте* без мягкого знака?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что в русском языке Ь после гортанных г, к, х встречается только в заимствованиях (Алигьери, кьянти, Донахью), в собственно же русских словах невозможен

Comment: Любопытно, что произношение в соответствии с такой записью требует внимания и некоторого усилия, иначе гь/хь произносятся твёрдо. Имя "Хью" ещё сложнее произнести со смягчением (либо слог произносится по частям, либо искажается ударный гласный). В словах же типа "адъютант", наоборот, "д" смягчается вопреки написанию (по другой причине: твёрдое произношение таких буквосочетаний подчёркнуто разделяет слово на смысловые части, напр. "подъязычный").

Answer (score 1):

По фонетическим причинам. Звук "гь" встречается только перед гласными и записывается без мягкого знака (напр. в слоге "ге").

Answer (score 0):

Как-то все вокруг да около.
Мягкий знак в "ляг" не пишется просто потому, что там **Г твердое**. И в "лягте" тоже.
Если произносящий этого не понимает, то рассказы о том, где и как возможен "ерь" после "глаголя" бесполезны.

> Есть такое правило
>
> > Мягкий знак в глаголах пишется в форме повелительного наклонения после
> >     согласных: отрежь, одень.

Правило такое есть. Но нигде не сказано, что в этих случаях он пишется всегда, даже тогда, когда он противоречит фонетике. А "Г" и "ГЬ" в русском языке означают ***разные*** звуки (в отличие, например, от сочетаний Ж/ЖЬ или Ч/ЧЬ), замена одного другим противоречила бы орфоэпическим нормам. Поэтому и прижилось написание "ляг" - вместо исторического "ляжь" (по правилам т. н. "первой палатализации").

Все сказанное не означает, конечно, что я в чем-то ставлю под сомнение истинность утверждений в других примерах. Просто они не прямо отвечают на вопрос.